# Unable to Receive Input from GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am basically making a program that calculates the perimeter and area of a certain shape. I am using the tkinter GUI in order to do this.

Anyways, I decided that I wanted the user to highlight the checkbutton when they are done inputting their numbers so that I know when to collect the data from the entry widget in tkinter, but it seems as though my checkbutton is not working.

```
def perTriangle(): #PerTriangle means the perimeter of a triangle. 
    tk.Label(window, text = "Enter in the Numbers: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 100)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 1: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 130)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry1.place(x = 1155, y = 130)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 2: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry2.place(x = 1155, y = 160)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 3: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 190)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry3.place(x = 1155, y = 190)
    check1 = tk.IntVar()
    cButton = tk.Checkbutton(window, text = "Enter: ", variable = check1)
    cButton.place(x = 1115, y = 220)
    if check1.get() == 1:
        num1 = float(entry1.get())
        num2 = float(entry2.get())
        num3 = float(entry3.get())
        ans = num1 + num2 + num3
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Your Answer is: ", str(ans))
```

Nothing runs after the checkbutton is checked off. I don't know what I am doing wrong here, because I think everything checks out, but it still doesn't work. I am not getting any syntax errors with this program.

I then tried to use multiple functions to see if that would do the trick:

```
def perTriangle():
    tk.Label(window, text = "Enter in the Numbers: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 100)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 1: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 130)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry1.place(x = 1155, y = 130)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 2: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry2.place(x = 1155, y = 160)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 3: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 190)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry3.place(x = 1155, y = 190)
    check1 = tk.IntVar()
    cButton = tk.Checkbutton(window, text = "Enter: ", variable = check1)
    cButton.place(x = 1115, y = 220)
    isUserDone(check1)


def isUserDone(x):
    if x.get() == 1:
        calculationPTriangle()


def calculationPTriangle():
    num1 = float(entry1.get())
    num2 = float(entry2.get())
    num3 = float(entry3.get())
    ans = num1 + num2 + num3
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Your Answer is: ", str(ans))
```

Again, I got the same result. What can I do to fix this problem? I appreciate any and all help! Thanks in advance!

Updated Code after Initial Edit:

```
def perTriangle():
    tk.Label(window, text = "Enter in the Numbers: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 100)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 1: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 130)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry1.place(x = 1155, y = 130)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 2: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry2.place(x = 1155, y = 160)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 3: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 190)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry3.place(x = 1155, y = 190)
    check1 = tk.IntVar()
    cButton = tk.Checkbutton(window, text = "Enter: ", variable = check1, command = calculationPTriangle)
    cButton.place(x = 1115, y = 220)

def calculationPTriangle():
    num1 = float(entry1.get())
    num2 = float(entry2.get())
    num3 = float(entry3.get())
    ans = num1 + num2 + num3
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Your Answer is: ", str(ans))
```

Comment: `GUI` doesn't work like `input()` - widgets don't wait for values and you check values in widgest before even `tkinter` display window.  Usually we use `Button` to run code which get values from widgets after we put values in widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `GUI` doesn't work like `input()` and widgets don't wait for your data and you check values in widget even before `tkinter` displays window. Or before you can chance to put data in widgets.

Usually we use `Button` to run code after we put code in widgets and then it have chance to get these values.

`Button` has `command=function_name` to assign function which will be run when you click button.

**BTW:** `command=` needs function's name without `()`

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    print('Entry:', entry.get())
    print('Checkbox:', checkbox_var.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Input')
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

checkbox_var = tk.IntVar()
checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Enter", variable=checkbox_var)
checkbox.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`Checkbutton` also has `command=` to run function when you change selection. But it will be executed when you select it but also when you unselect it.

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_change():
    print('Entry:', entry.get())
    print('Checkbox:', checkbox_var.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Input')
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

checkbox_var = tk.IntVar()
checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Enter: ", variable=checkbox_var, command=on_change)
checkbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Version with `global`

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_change():
    print('Entry:', entry.get())
    print('Checkbox:', checkbox_var.get())

def main():
    #global root   # if I would need `root` in other function
    #global label  # if I would need `label` in other function
    global entry
    global checkbox_var
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    label = tk.Label(root, text='Input')
    label.pack()
    
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    
    checkbox_var = tk.IntVar()
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Enter: ", variable=checkbox_var, command=on_change)
    checkbox.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
    
# --- main ---

main()
```

Comment: I tried to use your advice and my code is now updated in my original post. When I try to get the values in `entry1`, `entry2`, and, `entry3`, I get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.`

Comment: how do you use it ? it seems you assigned string to `entry1` instead of `Entry`. For example If you do `entry1 = entry1.get()` then you can't do again `entry1.get()`

Comment: when you create variable inside function then it is local variable and it doesn't change external/global variable - so if you created `entry1 = ""` outside function and later do `entry1 = tk.Entry()` inside function then it doesn't change `entry1 = ""`. You have to add `global entry1` inside function to inform function that it has to assign `Entry()` to external variable instead of creating local variable. See new code in answer